# Serial-port stability issue

Tags: c#, serial-port, serial-communication

I need to implement an application in c# which periodically sends commands over the serial-port (lets say every minute). There should nothing be received over the comport.
For stability issues I'd like to know following.

Is it better to open the comport for every communication and close it again or to hold the serial-port open the whole time?

**EDIT:** Please consider also, that the communication partner could also send some data to my com-interface. I am not interested in this data, therefore I never read it. Could an overrun occur in the buffer of the com-interface and cause problems?

Answer (score 1):

IMHO there is no difference for stability. Just every time you open the port, you must do the processing possible exceptional situations.

You can just read the data sent and nothing to do with them.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I added some additional considerations to my question, does this change anything?